# highlight elements on mouse over

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a problem building an element highlighter (when the mouse is over an element, highlight the element).

I think it's due to problems with child-parent elements (obviously if the mouse is on the child element only the child element should be highlighted),
Here's the JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TVtz7/

thats the JS

```
function highlight(elem,action) {
    if (action) {
        elem.css('border','1px solid red');
    }
    else {
        elem.css('border','');
    }
}
$('#body_wrapper *').mouseenter(function(e) {
    highlight($(this),1);

});
$('#body_wrapper *').mouseout(function(e) {
    highlight($(this),0);
});
```

Comment: any reason you dont use CSS `:hover`?

Comment: I want to do extra things other than just highlight them .. I plan to gather Class/ID and display it.. and then store it..

Comment: And what is actually the problem? You do not actually say it. In the fiddle the element that is being hovered over is highlighted

Comment: Go from the Title (I am an Item!) to the Gray box (parent element), it is not being highlighted even though it should be

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
function highlight(elem,action, e) {
    if (action) {
        elem.css('border','1px solid red');
    }
    else {
        elem.css('border','');
    }
 e.preventDefault();
e.StopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: still not working when going from title outside (as mentioned in the question), and error: Object #<Object> has no method 'StopPropagation'

Answer (score 0):

try belowed, its working. I added condition there so it will only highlight child most div only.

```
function highlight(elem,action, e) {
    if (action) {
        elem.css('border','1px solid red');
    }
    else {
        elem.css('border','');
    }
 e.preventDefault();
}

$('#body_wrapper *').mouseenter(function(e) {

    if($('.current-highlighted').length == 0){  
        $(this).addClass('current-highlighted');
        highlight($(this),1,e);
    }

});
$('#body_wrapper *').mouseout(function(e) {

    highlight($(this),0,e);
    $(this).removeClass('current-highlighted'); 
});
```